# how can i fix this? this item is unreachable because a previous item (item #1) is a more general match than this one

Tags: android, eclipse

i am making a game and i need to use 50-60 different buttons that i have made in photoshop.
eclipse gives me this error code

(this item is unreachable because a previous item (item #1) is a more general match than this one)

I have search for a answer on the web but the only thing i have found is this:

During each state change, the state list is traversed top to bottom and the first item that matches the current state is used—the selection is not based on the "best match," but simply the first item that meets the minimum criteria of the state.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Your first item matches always, place it at the end instead....

I am not that good with eclipse so i hope that you can give me a STEP BY STEP answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/level1one" />

**<item android:drawable="@drawable/level2femti" />**
// this one is the problem// 

<item android:drawable="@drawable/level3one" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/level3two" />  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/level3three" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/level4dager" />  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/level4timer" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/level4uker" />  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/level4måneder" />


</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selectors selects items from first item that matches current state of the view.
So for example if you have an item with state pressed true like:

```
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/level1one"/>
```

So if view is pressed this item would be selected but if you write another item with same state like:

```
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/level1one"/>
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/level2one"/>
```

Now both of the items are for state pressed so first one would be selected and the 2nd would never be used.

Any item with no state defined is the default item for ex:

```
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/level1one"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/level2one"/>
```

in the above example if view's state is pressed first item would be selected else 2nd.

if the first item was not present 2nd item would selected for pressed state as well.

now if you change the order:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/level2one"/>
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/level1one"/>
```

The first item here is for all the state(including pressed state) so the second item well never be used.

in your case your are having multiple items with same state(default) so after first item all are unreachable lines.

Answer (score 0):

You use different items for one state in selector.

You should to add state parameter to items. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/login_button"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/login_button_tap"/>
</selector>
```

Read about selectors in android:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList